# How to I leave a 4:3 rectangle space on my beamer slide for screen recording with video

Tags: beamer, teaching

I intend to record video lectures. I am using Beamer for making the slides. How can I keep a rectangle space with aspect ratio of 4:3 (actual resolution is 640x480) on any corner so that it remains blank and all the other content simply wraps around it on all slides. In this rectangle area, I will have my video feed (640x480) on and the screen recorder will record my video+audio and the slides on an 1920x1080 resolution. The rectangular area should remain blank (without any border) since the same slides will be distributed.

I have added the rectangle space in the image below as I would like to have it. I have no idea where to start searching for a solution. Can you give me some pointers or suggestions? [image: rectangle area should remain untouched.]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome. If I understand correctly, you want this rectangle to be present on all beamer slides and to broadcast live the conference you are having live. Is that it?

Comment: The rectangle is needed on all the beamer slides. A screenrecorder will capture the slides and the live video of my face will be resized to that rectangle.

Comment: Since nobody answered, you can find a solution here: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=625